# How to import aspose-imaging?

Tags: python, import, pypi, aspose

I can't install *`aspose-imaging`**.** i am using visual studio 2022 , python 3.9*

I tried to install directly from *pypl* using : pip install `aspose-imaging` , But i have these errors :

1-Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `aspose-imaging` (from versions: none)

2-No matching distribution found for `aspose-imaging`

Comment: It is called: [aspose-imaging-python-net](https://github.com/aspose-imaging/Aspose.Imaging-for-Python-Net?tab=readme-ov-file#get-started-with-asposeimaging-for-python-via-net)

Comment: You should run: pip install aspose-imaging-python-net